# Matrix-tree theorem via supersymmetry (i.e. Grassman algebras)

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, linear-algebra, co.combinatorics, supersymmetry

The [matrix-tree theorem](http://math.mit.edu/%7Elevine/18.312/alg-comb-lecture-19.pdf) states the number of spanning trees of a graph $G$ is equal to a modified determinant of the adjacency matrix or "graph Laplacian", $\Delta_G$:

$$\#\{ \text{spanning trees of }G  \}  = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \dots \lambda_n = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{ \det(\Delta_G - \epsilon I)}{\epsilon}.$$
Here $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues.

Apparently, Matrix-Tree [can be used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem) to compute effective resistances between points in Electrical networks or show the number of distinct labelled trees of size n.

[Grassman algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) (or supersymmetry) seems to be a great bookkeeping device which does a lot of the linear algebra for you.  Maybe the proof of that result can be simplified here.

"Fermions" and 1-forms are similar objects.  We can say $\psi_1\psi_2= - \psi_2 \psi_1$ or $ v \wedge  w = - w \wedge v $.  For fermions there's something called [Berezin integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berezin_integral) or [Grassman integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_integral).

$$ \int (a \psi + b ) d\psi= a \hspace{0.333in}\text{and}\hspace{0.333in} \int e^{\phi^T A \psi}\; d\phi d\psi = \det A$$
I am not sure what the analog is for 1-forms in the cotangent bundle of a manifold $T^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

---

Between the papers [arXiv:math.CO/0306396][6] by A Abdesselam and [arXiv:math-ph/0107005][7] by Brydges and Imbrie two approaches for proving this result arise:

- Grassmann integration (above)
- Forest-Root formula (below)

The [Forest-Root formula](http://www.newton.ac.uk/programmes/CSM/seminars/041109301.pdf) says, for any compactly supported function:

$$ f(\mathbf{0}) = \sum_{(F,R)} \int_{\mathbb{C}^N} f^{(F,R)} (\mathbf{t}) \left(-\frac{d^2 z}{\pi} \right)^N $$
Here the variables $t_i = |z_i|^2$ and $t_{ij} = |z_i - z_j|^2$ and sum is over all possible roots and forests.  Apparently it can be put even more concisely as:

$$\int_{\mathbb{C}^n} f(\tau) = f(0) $$

(for compactly supported functions) where the integral is over some ``supersymmetric" measure, $\tau = z \overline{z} + \frac{dz d\overline{z}}{2\pi i}$.

It also seems these kinds of "free-fermion" calculations lead to many generalizations of matrix-tree that I won't get into (including relations to [Branched Polymers](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.2325) and [Diffusion Limited Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation)).  Personally, I wonder what the cotangent bundle picture looks like for these.

---

The proofs in the two above papers are left as exercises, which more general results proven.  Mainly, I just would like to see the proofs the no-frills Matrix-Tree theorem from either of these two starting points

Answer (score 4):

Check out [this talk by Alan Sokal,](http://interacting.math.cnrs.fr/rutgers_Dec_07_slides.pdf) and references therein (on the title page).